# Dimensional analysis for the angle of friction (angle of response)?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, dimensional-analysis

I am supposed to find the angle of response θ for a cone shaped pile of sand given that the friction between the sand granulas is μ.
This is easily calculated as $θ = \tan(μ)$ with the help of a free-body diagram showing your common "body on an inclined plane" figure.

However, it gets complicated for me when I am supposed to confirm my result using dimensional analysis i.e. I am supposed to construct a dimensionless function for the angle using relevant physical quantities for building the pile.

I could go as easy as saying that the angle is given by the length of the arc divided by the radius (of the cone) and get a dimensionless constant C, which by comparison, will confirm the result. But it just seems too "easy".

Upon asking for clarification I got the answer "Assume that you do not know the result. If you would choose a more complicated model, could you come up with a completely different dependence of your angle on relevant physical parameters?"

I am completely stuck and would appreciate any help.

in the free body diagram the coefficient of the friction is called $μ_s$.
[image: Angle is equal to length of arc divided by radius]
[image: Free-body diagram]

Comment: FYI: it is known as angle of [repose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_repose) not response

Comment: Also your equation is incorrect; it's $\mu_s = \tan\theta$

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking, or what your problem is. You have already got a formula. It is trivial to confirm whether that formula is dimensionally correct. It is also trivial to construct dimensionless combinations of $m, g, \mu, r, l, h, \theta$ etc. Why are you rejecting an "easy" answer?

Comment: @nluigi Ah yes, meant  $tan^-1(μ_s)=θ$ if you look at the second photo attached, last line, I've written the correct ones... thanks for correcting :)